# indexOf("http") matches on http and https

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I have the following code,

```
var protocol = jQuery('script[src*="kaltura"]').attr("src");
protocol.toLowerCase().indexOf("http");
```

The problem is that `indexOf` is matching on http and https. How can I only get it to match on http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to check the protocol of the website only, check for `http://`:

```
protocol.toLowerCase().indexOf("http://");
```

Comment: Great thinking!! That is perfect, I will accept when the time allows for it